# Codeigniter only $route['default_controller'] works

Tags: codeigniter-3

This project worked until I cloned it on a different location, The only route which works now is `$route['default_controller']` when I try to access to another  route  I get an 404 error but I've changed nothing until the last time it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may hide the index.php from the url  by rewritting urls in .htaccess, Please check you have .htaccess file  in new location or right base path in .htaccess file.